# ATHENA MIN() function bringing back nulls

Tags: amazon-web-services, min, amazon-athena

I am attempting to bring back the smallest date of three attributes that is not null. There could be multiple rows so I need to group to find the lowest of date of the attribute for the key and the lowest of the three lowest numbers

[image]

So with the image below I would want to return 09/09/00 the problem is MIN() keeps bringing back null as the lowest value and operators do the same. Is there a good solution for this?

We want the min of the first and second date and if both of all of those dates are null return the min third_date

```
key date_1 date_2 Date_3
1 12/31/12 1/2/18 NULL
1 5/3/15 5/17/08 3/17/19
1 NULL 9/9/00 9/28/07
```

Comment: key date_1 date_2 Date_3
1 12/31/12 1/2/18 NULL
1 5/3/15 5/17/08 3/17/19
1 NULL 9/9/00 9/28/07

Comment: Please _edit_ your question to include the sample data as _text_.

Comment: Please show us the query you are using - from the [docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html): _"Except for count(), count_if(), max_by(), min_by() and approx_distinct(), all of these aggregate functions ignore null values and return null for no input rows or when all values are null"_ so `MIN` should ignore nulls and I was not able to repro your issue.

Comment: Min() in Athena appears to not exclude null values in our environment I came up with a solution however it is a bit resource intensive using the above union

Comment: @Drummerpolo15 what version of Athena engine are you using?  Also please share the query and sample data - I was not able to reproduce the issue with Athena. Also what is the type of dates columns? Also is there actually `null` value stored in the column or varchar `'NULL'`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `UNION` approach here:

```sql
SELECT "key", MIN(date) AS min_date
FROM
(
    SELECT "key", date_1 AS date FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "key", date_2 FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "key", date_3 FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY "key";
```

Note that you should avoid naming your columns `key`, which is usually a reserved SQL keyword.

Comment: Sorry I should have added we want the min of the first and second date and if both of all of those dates are null return the min third_date